# how to set the text position in pdfbox

Tags: servlets, pdfbox

i have use pdfbox for creating pdf but not getting sure how to set the text in x and y it will not come in proper format

```
PDDocument document=new PDDocument();
    PDPage blank=new PDPage();
    PDFont font=PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD; 
    document.addPage(blank);

    PDPageContentStream content=new PDPageContentStream(document, blank);
    content.beginText();
    int i=0;
    int  x=20;
    int y=700;
while(i<5){
content. newLineAtOffset(x, y);
            content.setFont(font, 12);
            content.showText(id);
            content.showText(role);
            i++;
            y=-20;
}
content.endText();
content.close();
document.save("BlankPage.pdf");
document.close();[it will increase x and i dont want to increase possition of x][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1A6I.jpg
```

Comment: *will not come in proper format* - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the OP has not explained what exactly he means by *not coming in proper format*.

Looking at his code, though, it seems like he thinks

```
content.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
```

will position the new line at the given **x**, **y** as *absolute* coordinates. This is not the case. Instead **x**, **y** are *relative* to the previous line coordinates which are set to **0**, **0** in the PDF instruction generated by `content.beginText()`.

This actually already is hinted at by the `Offset` in `newLineAtOffset` and made clear in the JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The Td operator.
 * Move to the start of the next line, offset from the start of the current line by (tx, ty).
 *
 * @param tx The x translation.
 * @param ty The y translation.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error writing to the stream.
 * @throws IllegalStateException If the method was not allowed to be called at this time.
 */
public void newLineAtOffset(float tx, float ty) throws IOException
```

Thus, most likely he wants do something like

```
int x=20;
int y=700;
content.beginText();
content.setFont(font, 12);
content.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    content.showText(id);
    content.showText(role);
    content.newLineAtOffset(0, -20);
}
content.endText();
```